Pandas getting first alphabetically value of each group
Suppose I have a dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'B': ['A', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'D']
})

And I am trying to get first alphabetically value of each group
When I tried this
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')
 

I will get this result
    A   B
0   foo A
1   foo A
2   bar F
3   bar F
4   bar F

What should I do to get a result like this?
    A   B
0   foo A
1   foo A
2   bar B
3   bar B
4   bar B


If you don't care about foo/bar relative ordering, then just df = df.sort_values(["A", "B"]); df["B"] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first').

Do you have lower case letter, how would you like the order of lower case letter and upper case letter?

I don't have lowercase letters yet. But is there any way to sort despite lowercase/uppercase?

IIUC, sort your dataframe first then groupby-transform and let pandas use intrinsic index alignment to align your results with your original dataframe:
df['new_b'] = df.sort_values('B').groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')

Output:
     A  B new_b
0  foo  A     A
1  foo  C     A
2  bar  F     B
3  bar  B     B
4  bar  D     B


The first letter in alphabetical/lexicographic order is the min:
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('min')

Output:
     A  B
0  foo  A
1  foo  A
2  bar  B
3  bar  B
4  bar  B

Assuming mixed case you could use:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'B': ['A', 'C', 'F', 'b', 'D']
})

df['B'] = df['B'].str.upper().groupby(df['A']).transform('min')

Or, if you want to keep the original case:
df['B'] = (df.sort_values(by='B', key=lambda x: x.str.upper())
             .groupby('A').transform('first')
          )

Output:
     A  B
0  foo  A
1  foo  A
2  bar  b
3  bar  b
4  bar  b


Always got to one up me. :) +1

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'B': ['A', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'D']
})

# Use the `min` method to get the first alphabetically sorted value for each group
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('min')

print(df)


In the min function, one finds the first value in each group alphabetically.
The transform method applies this function to each group and returns a Series that has the same length as the original DataFrame.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
